# How is it determined whether a chromosome is maternal or paternal for imprinting?

Tags: genetics, chromosome, allele

For imprinting, how does the cell determine which chromosome is maternal and which is paternal? For example, in the parental imprinting of insulin-like growth factor 2 (Igf2) on chr7 (autosome), how is it determined which is paternal and to be imprinted?

Answer (score 2):

Imprinting occurs via DNA methylation in gametes. Different parts of the genome are methylated in either eggs or sperm, and this then marks those genes throughout the lifespan of the organism, inherited epigenetically across cell divisions. See:

Wood, A. J., & Oakey, R. J. (2006). Genomic imprinting in mammals: emerging themes and established theories. PLoS genetics, 2(11), e147.